# SwiftUI Exclude an Swift Package when previewing macOS target

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I have a iOS SwiftUI app that make uses of a few Swift Packages (download with Xcode's built-in support for SPM). I now want to port my app to macOS (not with Catalyst, a native version but sharing portions of SwiftUI code), so I made a new macOS target.

I can press the run button to run the macOS target just fine. However, since one of my Swift Package make uses of UIKit (to work with UIViewRepresentable, however, this library is not used in the Mac version), the preview won't build because it is trying to build the library that has UIKit, which is not available on the Mac (it's weird because I can run, but not preview).

I double checked to make sure that my Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content is empty on the Mac target.

Anything else that's going wrong here?

**Update**:
The issue is still present on Xcode 11.4 (iOS 13.4/macOS 10.15.4)

Comment: Yes, confirm same happens to me - it looks like Xcode bug due to run-time build info caching.. Sometimes it helps clean-restart-rebuild with active different target, sometimes it is fixed automatically (magically) by itself after changing SwiftUI module (so different preview is started generating). You can submit Apple feedback.

Comment: @Asperi yep, submitted (FB7624779)